# How to prevent discounting to zero in calculating ngrams?

Tags: nlp, n-gram

I'm using SRILM's ngram-count command line utility in an attempt to calculate a trigram model for a subset of the Gutenberg corpus.  The command line is:

```
 -order 3 -kndiscount -text {$text} -lm {$lm} -gt2min 10 -gt3min 5 -vocab {$vocab} -unk
```

However, some of my lines are coming up as discounted to 0 (or at least that's why I believe is happening.

```
-5.018952   roaming
-4.189117   roar    -0.2053203
-4.30369    roared  0    <-- discounted to zero?
```

This also occurs if I'm using -gt1min 0 or any other value and the minimum threshold is realized.  How do I prevent this from happening?  It's causing problems when I try to convert this to an n-gram based FST and observe input with one of these words in the input sentence.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial (page 17)](http://berlin.csie.ntnu.edu.tw/Berlin_Research/Surevy/Lectures/20080512-SRILM%20Tutorial.pdf), the number you are referring to is the *backoff weight*. For more information, you could read [this](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ngram-discount.7.html).